# Serialization with JDBC with MySQL, JAVA REST and Python REST

Tags: java, python, mysql, rest, jdbc

I have a project in which i use JDBC with MySQL to store some user information, Java REST for the server and Python REST for the client.

My question is: by default(i haven't changed anything in the configurations), are the http requests from the client serialized on the server's side? I ask this because i'd like to know if i need to make the database insert/delete querys thread-safe or something.

Comment: What framework are you using for Java REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they need to be thread safe.  You should be writing your Java server as if it were single threaded, because a Java EE app server will assign a thread per incoming request.

You also need to think about database isolation and table locking.  Will you allow "dirty reads" or should your transactions be serializable?   Should you SELECT FOR UPDATE?  That's a database setting, separate from threading considerations.

Comment: "Java EE app server will assign a thread per incoming request" So each http request has it's own thread... oky doky. That's all i needed to know. Thought it was like that, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: The possessive is "its"; "it's" is short for "it is".  Substitute that into your comment and see if it still makes sense.

Comment: Oh shush...english is not my first language, and it's early here, haven't had my coffee yet :)

Comment: All the more reason to correct you.  If I ever decided to learn more than the one I was fluent in I'd thank you to correct me.

Comment: In fact i'm not that bad at English, that earlier thing was just a plain mistake. But it's intriguing how people (me in this case) try and conjure up an excuse for their mistakes instead of saying "thanks, i made a mistake/typo/etc" :D

Comment: I didn't say your English was bad.  The (very simple) mistake you made is common even from folks who speak it as a first language.  No worries.